# How to add google places autocomplete to xcode with swift (tutorial)

Tags: ios, xcode, google-maps, autocomplete, google-places-api

I want to add google places autocomplete to xcode with swift, so users can search on a city and press enter, so should the app show that city on the map.

I´m using google maps, so it has to be connected to that map and the search bar would i like to have in the navi-bar (just above the map)

Does anyone know a good tutorial to do that??

Answer (score 8):

For Swift 3:

1- Select your podfile and type : pod 'GooglePlaces'

2- In the appDelegate, add your API Key : 
`GMSPlacesClient.provideAPIKey("YOUR KEY")` (Import the GooglePlaces)

3- Use this code in your viewController that contains the googleMap:

```
    // This code snippet demonstrates adding a
// full-screen Autocomplete UI control

import UIKit
import GooglePlaces

class ViewController: UIViewController {

  // TODO: Add a button to Main.storyboard to invoke onLaunchClicked.

  // Present the Autocomplete view controller when the button is pressed.
  @IBAction func onLaunchClicked(sender: UIButton) {
    let acController = GMSAutocompleteViewController()
    acController.delegate = self
    present(acController, animated: true, completion: nil)
  }
}

extension ViewController: GMSAutocompleteViewControllerDelegate {

  // Handle the user's selection.
  func viewController(_ viewController: GMSAutocompleteViewController, didAutocompleteWith place: GMSPlace) {
    print("Place name: \(place.name)")
    print("Place address: \(place.formattedAddress)")
    print("Place attributions: \(place.attributions)")
    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
  }

  func viewController(_ viewController: GMSAutocompleteViewController, didFailAutocompleteWithError error: Error) {
    // TODO: handle the error.
    print("Error: \(error)")
    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
  }

  // User cancelled the operation.
  func wasCancelled(_ viewController: GMSAutocompleteViewController) {
    print("Autocomplete was cancelled.")
    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
  }
}
```

Comment: line `acController.delegate = self` give that error:

_Cannot assign value of type 'MyController' to type 'GMSAutocompleteViewControllerDelegate?'_

Comment: Error above solved:
Forgot rename the extension from:  
`extension ViewController: GMSAutocompleteViewControllerDelegate {`
to  
`extension MyController: GMSAutocompleteViewControllerDelegate {`

Comment: Simple & sweet answer.

Comment: how to get lan and log from these delegates ??

Answer (score 7):

Not exactly tutorials, but there are a few resources on Github, with people providing libraries and code samples to achieve what you're asking for.

- SPGooglePlacesAutocomplete (https://github.com/spoletto/SPGooglePlacesAutocomplete) is very popular and has many features, but it's written in Objective-C
- iOS Google Places Autocomplete (https://github.com/watsonbox/ios_google_places_autocomplete) is more recent, written in Swift, and also contains some examples.
- lots of others...

Even without proper tutorials, you can still check out these libraries and understand how their code works to get some inspiration if you want to write your own components.

As a sidetone, Google also has this page, but it's not a dedicated tutorial for iOS apps, just some useful explanations of how their API works: https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/autocomplete#examples

Comment: I know them both, but the first one is in objective C and i have no ide on have to convert it.

Comment: the second one is full of fails

Comment: I am using the second one on a project with no issues at the moment.

Comment: There is a site that you can use to convert objective c to swift. It's got a few bugs but it can give you a decent understanding of how the code is different. Check it out -> objectivec2swift.net/#/converter

Answer (score 5):

You can try one for wrapper to implement Autocompletion for Place API with Google:

**https://github.com/mrugrajsinh/MVAutocompletePlaceSearchTextField**

Its very simple drop-in control and subclass of **UITextField** so using by binding Class with simple **UITextField** you can achive Auto completion dropdown similar as ***Uber*** and many popular app does.

Comment: This library doesn't work for Swift. See that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34060166/im-using-a-google-maps-autocomplete-wrapper-but-im-failing-to-conform-to-a-de

Comment: Installed this before realizing it doesn't work for swift

Comment: i m using ur lib earlier it was working nowadays when i click on places after entering location it doesnot work until i hold cell @Mrug

Answer (score 3):

Here's a [tutorial](http://ashishkakkad.com/2015/02/google-place-autocomplete-view-with-swift-language-through-alamofire-networking-library/) I came across which is based on my [ios_google_places_autocomplete](https://github.com/watsonbox/ios_google_places_autocomplete) code.

[@Frederik](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4566828/frederik-j%C3%B8rgensen): If you've had a problem with the library, please [create an issue](https://github.com/watsonbox/ios_google_places_autocomplete/issues) describing it.

Answer (score 2):

please check this one 110% work.
http://sweettutos.com/2015/09/30/how-to-use-the-google-places-autocomplete-api-with-google-maps-sdk-on-ios/

Answer (score 1):

Use this latest repo. with swift 2.0

Just download zip file of project and open pod file and write **pod 'GoogleMaps'**  and save it open terminal and install pod.

Enjoy!!!

[RKAutoCompletePlaceSearch](http://github.com/RonakKalavadia/RKAutoCompletePlaceSearch)

Answer (score 0):

Since the question was asked, Google has added UI elements to the iOS SDK for this sort of workflow. Check out the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/places/ios-api/autocomplete).

Answer (score 0):

## Simple and lightweight solution for Swift users !

I also created a library to make these simple request without including any framework of third party library. You can also maintain cache for Autocomplete with the library.

To use to library follow these steps : -

#### step-1 Import `GoogleApiHelper` into your project.

#### step-2 Initialise  `GoogleApiHelper`

```
GoogleApi.shared.initialiseWithKey("API_KEY")
```

#### step-3 Call the methods

```
var input = GInput()
input.keyword = "San francisco"
GoogleApi.shared.callApi(input: input) { (response) in
    if let results = response.data as? [GApiResponse.Autocomplete], response.isValidFor(.autocomplete) {
        //Enjoy the Autocomplete Api
    } else { print(response.error ?? "ERROR") }
}
```

[You can find the library here](https://github.com/tryWabbit/Google-Api-Helper)

[image]