# I'm using a google maps autocomplete wrapper, but I'm failing to conform to a delegate. How is this happening?

Tags: swift

I am using https://github.com/mrugrajsinh/MVAutocompletePlaceSearchTextField

To create a custom autocomplete UI for my app when entering addresses. However, I can't seem to conform to the protocol although everything is there. The bridging header and group is correctly handled, since I can access the methods no problem in my VC, but I can't compile since it's not conforming.

The objective C protocols are:

```
@protocol PlaceSearchTextFieldDelegate;

@interface MVPlaceSearchTextField : MLPAutoCompleteTextField
@property(nonatomic,strong)NSString *strApiKey;
@property(nonatomic,strong)IBOutlet id<PlaceSearchTextFieldDelegate>placeSearchDelegate;
@end

@protocol PlaceSearchTextFieldDelegate <NSObject>

-(void)placeSearch:(MVPlaceSearchTextField*)textField ResponseForSelectedPlace:(GMSPlace*)responseDict;
-(void)placeSearchWillShowResult:(MVPlaceSearchTextField*)textField;
-(void)placeSearchWillHideResult:(MVPlaceSearchTextField*)textField;
-(void)placeSearch:(MVPlaceSearchTextField*)textField ResultCell:(UITableViewCell*)cell withPlaceObject:(PlaceObject*)placeObject atIndex:(NSInteger)index;
@end
```

My swift code is:

```
extension AddAddressViewController: PlaceSearchTextFieldDelegate {

    //MARK: Placesearch Textfield Delegates

    func placeSearch(textField: MVPlaceSearchTextField!, responseForSelectedPlace responseDict: GMSPlace!) {
        return
    }

    func placeSearch(textField: MVPlaceSearchTextField!, resultCell cell: UITableViewCell!, withPlaceObject placeObject: PlaceObject!, atIndex index: Int) {
    }

    func placeSearchWillHideResult(textField: MVPlaceSearchTextField!) {
    }

    func placeSearchWillShowResult(textField: MVPlaceSearchTextField!) {
    }

}
```

It's all there. But I get the type AddAddressViewController does not conform to protocol PlaceSearch...

What else am I missing? I have properly subclassed the textfield I'm using, and created an outlet. Also properly delegated it, so it should all hit!

```
#ifndef Bridging_Header_h
#define Bridging_Header_h

#import <GoogleMaps/GoogleMaps.h>
#import <FBSDKLoginKit/FBSDKLoginKit.h>
#import <FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKCoreKit.h>
#import "MVPlaceSearchTextField.h"


#endif /* Bridging_Header_h */
```

EDIT:

Here I used a objective C to swift translator to directly convert the protocol methods. However, now I get a compile error saying that the arguments for the protocols are different with a suggested fix-it of reverting back to lower case...

```
func placeSearch(textField: MVPlaceSearchTextField, ResponseForSelectedPlace responseDict: GMSPlace) {
    self.view.endEditing(true)
    NSLog("SELECTED ADDRESS :%@", responseDict)
}

func placeSearchWillShowResult(textField: MVPlaceSearchTextField) {
}

func placeSearchWillHideResult(textField: MVPlaceSearchTextField) {
}

func placeSearch(textField: MVPlaceSearchTextField, ResultCell cell: UITableViewCell, withPlaceObject placeObject: PlaceObject, atIndex index: Int) {
    if index % 2 == 0 {
        cell.contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 0.9, alpha: 1.0)
    }
    else {
        cell.contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    }
}
```

Comment: Check capitalization of parameters names at your methods.

Comment: Did you add all your files with classes like `MVPlaceSearchTextField`, `PlaceObject`, `GMSPlace`  to bridging file? can you show your bridge file?

Comment: @katleta3000 I added the bridging header. I think the MVP... is all I need to import, since it's all that was in the example Xcode project in git, right?

Comment: `ResultCell` and `ResponseForSelectedPlace` has different capitalization

Comment: @katleta3000 Swift compiler gave me errors with a suggested correction to revert back to lowercase saying that the argument names between that and the protocol methods are different.

Comment: @katleta3000 also, check the edit. There is the new methods I used, which still comes out to the error

Comment: @PeterLi Hi, have you found the solution then? I'm having the exact same problem with this library. Have you found any alternatives to solve the autocomplete on iOS?

Answer (score 1):

Try this code for Swift:

```
@objc(placeSearch:ResponseForSelectedPlace:) func placeSearch(textField: MVPlaceSearchTextField!, responseForSelectedPlace responseDict: GMSPlace!) {
}

@objc(placeSearch:ResultCell:withPlaceObject:atIndex:) func placeSearch(textField: MVPlaceSearchTextField!, resultCell cell: UITableViewCell!, withPlaceObject placeObject: PlaceObject!, atIndex index: Int) {
}

@objc(placeSearchWillShowResult:) func placeSearchWillShowResult(textField: MVPlaceSearchTextField!) {
}

@objc(placeSearchWillHideResult:) func placeSearchWillHideResult(textField: MVPlaceSearchTextField!) {   
}
```

Comment: I was having exactly the same problem, and this fixed it.

Comment: some times it shows the places and sometimes not using MVPlaceSearchTextField @webbcode what can be the issue

Answer (score 0):

Have you done this ? In Build Settings, search swift Compiler, install Objective-C Compatibility Header is YES. The Objective-C Bridging Header is your_project/******-bridging-Header.h,such as this, Test/Test-bridging-Header.h,try to build the app to ensure that there is no error in this.

Comment: Yes. The bridging header is working perfectly. I am able to access methods within the objective C class I imported. Just that the view controller is not conforming to the delegate..

Comment: Can your post your project to github for me ?? I just not confirm remember that view controller can not be delegate in new ios app.

Answer (score 0):

Hey try this one for latest swift 2.0

just download project and open pod file and write  **pod 'GoogleMaps'** and save it.
install pod with terminal and enjoy!!

[RKAutoCompletePlaceSearch](http://github.com/RonakKalavadia/RKAutoCompletePlaceSearch)